# How to assert property of objects at a list?

Tags: assertj

I am trying to have proper assertion (with implicit `null` checks) for a property of a list element.

- The first assertion is working as expected, except that it will generate no proper error message if `actual` is `null`.
- The second is supposed to provide proper `null` check for `actual`, but it's not compiling.

Is there an option tweak the second assertion to make it work?

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class ExampleTest {

    private static class Sub {

        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private static class Example {

        private List<Sub> subs;

        public List<Sub> getSubs() {
            return subs;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        Example actual = null;

        assertThat(actual.getSubs())//not null safe
                .extracting(Sub::getValue)
                .contains("something");

//        assertThat(actual)
//                .extracting(Example::getSubs)
//                .extracting(Sub::getValue)//not compiling
//                .contains("something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For type-specific assertions, [`extracting(Function, InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) should be used:

```
assertThat(actual)
    .extracting(Example::getSubs, as(list(Sub.class)))
    .extracting(Sub::getValue) // compiles
    .contains("something");
```

- [`Assertions.as(InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#as(org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) is an optional syntax sugar to improve readability
- [`InstanceOfAssertFactories.list(Class)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/InstanceOfAssertFactories.html#list(java.lang.Class)) provides the list-specific assertions after the `extracting` call